# Несовпадение путей импорта на сервере и PyCharm

Tags: python

Есть следующая иерархия папок

```
Project
-------\app
-----------\main.py
-----------\smth.py
```

Работая в PyCharm, чтобы импортировать smth.py в main.py мне нужно прописать

```
import app.smth
```

Когда я загружаю все на сервер, не меняя иерархии, постоянно приходится менять на

```
import smth
```

Можно ли как-то указать, чтобы иерархия как в PyCharm сохранялась?

Comment: тьфу, на автомате скопировал названия файлов, но нет, на сервере так не сработает

Comment: Если не работает, значит неправильно запускаете сервер. Обновите вопрос и укажите какие команды используете. Добавьте `app/__init__.py`, чтобы обозначить Питон пакет.